# Finding a parent element (not direct parent) based on partial match bot both parent id and child value

Tags: xpath

I have the following setup

```
<Ancestor_element_*****> Ancestor value
L
......
 L
  <Child_element> Child value *****
```

I have part of the child value and part of the ancestor node name. I need to get the Ancestor value (I do not know the exact level of nesting). Can this be done via an XPath query?

Comment: Do you mean "ancestor" by "parent"?

Comment: Yes, I do. I edited the original post.

Comment: Well, you certainly select `ancestor::*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Ancestor_element_')]` to select certain ancestor elements by a part of their name. It is not immediately clear to me what you consider the "ancestor value" in the context of XPath, whether you want the whole string value or only the one of the first text node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a child element whose text contains "Child value", then you want its ancestor whose name contains "Ancestor_element", and you want its text value:

```
//Child_element[contains(text(),'Child value')]
    /ancestor::*[contains(name(),'Ancestor_element')]/text()
```

Tested against

```
<Root>
  <Ancestor_element_1>Ancestor value
  <Something/>
  <Something_in_between>
    <Child_element> Child value 1</Child_element>
  </Something_in_between>
  </Ancestor_element_1>
</Root>
```

in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh).